# Ip conflict in windows 10

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I'm using windows 10, and everything was runing smoothly with my internet until i just got a message:

> Blockquote The specified Ip address 192.168.1.109, now it replaced with 192.168.1.104 . This computer is now locked contact your administrator.

First i'm using network with cisco router and a swithc. When i unplug the ethernet cable from the computer everything goes fine - I restart and everything goes well, except of not having internet. When I plug back the ethernet cable the same error goes again. Any idea what is wrong and how i can fix this ?

Comment: Is .109 the computer's own IP address? Is your computer configured for static addressing or DHCP? Are you the router's owner/administrator? Can you post a screenshot (or at least a photo) of the error message?

Comment: Sec please, give me just one moment

Comment: here is a link https://ibb.co/JdZXW71

Comment: it just locks, i can't type, i can't do anything till i restart and unplug the cable

Comment: I have the router's username and password

Comment: Is this your own computer, or is it managed by a company? From the message text I'm not sure, but from thr photo it _looks like_ it's got malware in it. Either malware or some semi-legit "remote management tool", at any rate.